# How can I change the color of the UITabBar top border by creating a UIImage programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uitabbar

From my understanding, the only way to *change the color* of the top border is to set the background image (320x49, with pixel line at top). It seems to me that this is the only way (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Is there a way to do this *without* using an image file? For example, someone helped me change the NavigationBar bottom border by creating a UIImage from code:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage.colorForNavBar(UIColor.redColor())

extension UIImage {   
    class func colorForNavBar(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor)
        CGContextFillRect(context, rect)

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return image
    }
}
```

This solution actually works well; it changes the color of my bottom border.

I tried to apply this to the TabBar, but nothing changes at all.

`UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage.colorForNavBar(.redColor())`

Comment: Did you set both `shadowImage` and `backgroundImage`? If you set only one of them, it won't work.

Comment: @TIMEX See my answer for an alternative solution to using a `UIImage`. My solution preserves the bar translucency, so the blur effect will remain active.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You've pretty much answered your own question.  You can do the same thing with your `UITabBar` as you did with your `UINavigationBar`.  If you want to change the shadow image (i.e. the "top border"), then you have to change the background image.  Straight from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBar_Class/):

> The custom shadow image for the tab bar. This attribute is ignored if the tab bar does not also have a custom background image. To set this attribute programmatically, use the shadowImage property.

In your own question you seem to be aware of this:

> the only way to change the color of the top border is to set the background image (320x49, with pixel line at top)

Except that it's not the background image that has a line at the top.  You just have to set the background image to anything, then you can set the shadow image to your preference.

If you open up the simple "tabbed application" template within Xcode, you'll find that adding these two lines of code (and your `UIImage` extension code) indeed work:

```
// White background with red border on top
UITabBar.appearance().backgroundImage = UIImage.colorForNavBar(.whiteColor())
UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage.colorForNavBar(.redColor())
```

[image: Tab Bar]

Comment: For those jumping straight to this answer - note that "colorForNavBar" is a custom UIImage extension function that you can find in the original question.

Answer (score 14):

Here is the Swift 3 solution:

```
extension UIImage {
    class func colorForNavBar(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
        //    Or if you need a thinner border :
        //    let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 1.0, height: 0.5)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        context!.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        context!.fill(rect)

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return image!
    }
}
```

used with the code above in the viewDidLoad of the UITabBarController

```
UITabBar.appearance().backgroundImage = UIImage.colorForNavBar(color: .white)
UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage.colorForNavBar(color: .red)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide an different image for `UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundImage`.

For example:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundImage = UIImage.colorForNavBar(.blackColor())
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage.colorForNavBar(.redColor())
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

What about simply subclassing UITabBar and adding a new sublayer to the view in layoutSubviews.

Swift example:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    let topBorder = CALayer()

    let borderHeight: CGFloat = 2

    topBorder.borderWidth = borderHeight
    topBorder.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    topBorder.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: -1, width: self.frame.width, height: borderHeight)

    self.layer.addSublayer(topBorder)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Normally, the other answers got it right - you have to set both a background image and a shadow image. However, doing so will cause the bar to drop its translucency (blur); even if you set a transparent image, the bar will be transparent, not translucent.

We also had a similar need, but we wanted to preserve the translucency of the bar. Instead of setting a shadow image, we subclassed the bar, and put a hairline subview with a color we want. When the bar lays out its subviews, we set the frame of the hairline to be the width of the bar, and a pixel exactly.

See [my GitHub demo project](https://github.com/LeoNatan/LNColoredHairlineTabBar).

Here is a screenshot of the result:

[image: Colored hairline tab bar]

After you include my subview in your project, just use the following line to set the color:

```
if let tabBar = tabBarController?.tabBar as? ColoredHairlineTabBar {
    tabBar.hairlineColor = ... //Your color
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Best solution for me

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an extension to create an image of a certain size, UIImage has a perfectly good constructor for that.

To prevent losing the translucent blur, you can set the bar tint color instead of a background image. You can also use the screen scale to make sure the border is one pixel, like the original border was:

```
    let hairlineHeight = CGFloat(1) / UIScreen.main.scale
    tabBar.barTintColor = .white
    tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage(color: .black, size: CGSize(width: 1, height: hairlineHeight))
```

Comment: Initializer for UIImage using color and size no longer works, compiler would show this error "UIImage?' initializer is inaccessible due to 'fileprivate' protection level" if you try to use it. I guess this API is private as of now.